# Equal query in Elasticsearch by Nest client

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

```
public class User 
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

client.Index(new User { Email ="test@test.te" });
```

Query in Linq C# for example :

```
rep.Where(user=>user.Email=="test@test.te");
```

That works correctly.

I use same query in Nest:

```
client.Search<Post>(q => q
.Query(qu => qu
.Term(te=>te.OnField("email").Value("test@test.te"))));
```

Document result count is zero!!

But :

```
client.Search<Post>(q => q
.Query(qu => qu
.Term(te=>te.OnField("email").Value("test"))));
```

Document result count is 1 - why?

How I can make equal-query in ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all because analyzers. Your document is parsed to terms while indexing, which means that elasticsearch stores something like an array of strings `["test", "test", "te"]` in row with your document. Depending on what anayzer is configured (I guess it's [standard](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) one), you may get different terms decomposition. On the other side, your term request is not analyzed; that's why first request returns nothing - there's no such string as "test@test.te" in index strings `["test", "test", "te"]`, but there's a "test" string, so you get results for the second one. In your case you should use [query_string query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html), but beware of the fact that such queries are analyzed too. It means, that if you index two documents, say `{"Email":"test@test.te"}` and `{"Email":"test@gmail.com"}`, without any flags query `{"query":{"query_string":{"default_field":"Email","query":"test@test.te"}}}` will return both documents because both of them contain `"test"` string in the index. To avoid this, use something like `{"default_field":"Email","query":"test@test.te", "default_operator":"AND"}}}` - default default operator is `"OR"`.

Speaking of NEST, use query like

```
client.Search<Post>(q => q
    .Query(qu => qu
    .QueryString(qs=>qs
        .OnField(x=>x.Email).Query("test@test.te").Operator(Operator.and)
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: How can I pass the operator as a string in the above query??